# Program using up all my memory

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am working on a texture synthesis project.  I am almost finished, however my process is taking ~2gb of memory while it is running.  I thought I was freeing all of my calloc'ed arrays, but I could be wrong.  C++ isn't my specialty.

I know triple pointers were the wrong way to go about it in C++ but I am just more comfortable with them at the moment.  Let me know if you need to see more code.  Thank you.

MetaPic declaration

```
class MetaPic
{
    public:
        Pic* source;
        Pixel1*** meta;
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
        MetaPic();
        MetaPic(Pic*);
        MetaPic(const MetaPic&);
        MetaPic(int, int, int);
        MetaPic& operator=(const MetaPic&);
        ~MetaPic();
        void allocateMetaPic();
        void copyPixelData();
        void copyToOutput(Pic*&);
        void copyToMetaOutput(MetaPic&, int, int);
        void copyToSample(MetaPic&, int, int);
        void freeMetaPic();

};
```

Allocating the triple pointer

```
    void MetaPic::allocateMetaPic()
{
    meta = (Pixel1***)calloc(x, sizeof(Pixel1**));

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        meta[i] = (Pixel1**)calloc(y, sizeof(Pixel1*));
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            meta[i][j] = (Pixel1*)calloc(z, sizeof(Pixel1));
        }
    }
}
```

Deallocating the triple pointer

```
void MetaPic::freeMetaPic()
{
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < z; i++)
            free(meta[i][j]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        free(meta[i]);

    free(meta);
}
```

Destructor

```
MetaPic::~MetaPic()
{
    freeMetaPic();
}
```

= Operator

```
MetaPic& MetaPic::operator=(const MetaPic& mp)
{
    freeMetaPic();

    source = mp.source;
    x = mp.x;
    y = mp.y;
    z = mp.z;
    allocateMetaPic();
    copyPixelData();

    return *this;
}
```

Copy constructor

```
MetaPic::MetaPic(const MetaPic& mp)
{
    source = mp.source;
    x = mp.x;
    y = mp.y;
    z = mp.z;
    allocateMetaPic();
    copyPixelData();
}
```

Comment: Where are the calls to alloc?

Comment: @sbooth Opps copied the wrong function. Let me fix that...fixed.

Comment: Have you tried counting how many allocs and frees you use? i.e. have an `allocateCount` and `freeCount` integer that get incremented every time you call `alloc` and `free` respectively. Then you can compare the values and see if they match.

Comment: -1 The information you provide is not directly related to the question, and not even to what you say it is about (e.g. you're talking about allocation and then presenting a copy function that doesn't allocate anything).

Comment: Also, what are the dimensions (x, y, z) of the matrix?

Comment: @Bowie Owens There are many of these pictures so they are of various sizes.  Most of them are 23 x 23 x 3, 100 x 100 x 3, and 70 x 70 x 3

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach, the OP updated his question, note.

Comment: I would use STL containers instead of pointers and arrays. I also recommend new/delete instead of malloc/free, since you don't need to worry about memory sizes. The compiler handles most of the heavy lifting, making it easier on you. This may be C++, but it is not object-oriented.

Comment: Are you sure your copy constructor and assignment operator do the correct thing?

Comment: @sth No I am not.  They could be wrong.  I never directly use the assignment operator, but I have one implemented.  I'll post them for review.

Comment: I asked about the dimensions because O(n^3) can get big quick. If you do need to deal with large n in the future, you might need to find a different way to represent your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When freeing you seem to be using the wrong terminating values in your loops. Just make the freeMetaPic function undo what the allocate function does, ie:

```
void MetaPic::freeMetaPic()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            free(meta[i][j]);
        }

        free(meta[i])
    }

    free(meta);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Memory freed with `free()` is not always returned to the OS when free()d - it may only be made available for allocation *within the same process*. To confirm this, run your program under a memory leak checker such as valgrind, and see if it reports any leaks when your program exits. Additionally, as [Eric points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425787/36723), you seem to be using the wrong terminating conditions for your deallocation loop.

If you would like to increase the chance that memory can be returned to the OS, try allocating your entire array with a single malloc or calloc call, and dividing it up into all the sub-arrays yourself - large single allocations often get special handling that (as a side effect) makes them easy to return to the OS. You could also flatten your array - that is, allocate one big `mx * my * mz`-element array, and access elements with e.g. `z + mz * (y + my * x)` (this will also be significantly faster than using multiple levels of pointers).

I would recommend just using a library that does this kind of contiguous multidimensional array allocation and lookup for you, such as the [boost multidimensional array library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html). It's far less error-prone that way, and it's going to be much faster than doing multi-level pointer lookups.

For reference, here's how using boost multidimensional arrays might look:

```
class MetaPic {
  // ...
  typedef boost::multi_array<Pixel1, 3> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;

  array_type image;
};

void MetaPic::allocateMetaPic() {
  image.resize(boost::extents[x][y][z]);
}

void MetaPic::freeMetaPic() {
  // this is only needed to try to force the array to be freed early; you can
  // instead simply allow it to be default-destroyed when MetaPic is destroyed
  image.resize(boost::extents[1][1][1]);
}
```

Accessing elements in this `image` can be done with normal syntax (ie, `image[i][j][k]`). Note that it's recommended to use the `index` type for array indices, but you can choose to use regular `int`s instead if you know they'll be in range.